# Regular expression to find characters between ##

Tags: java, regex

I have text as below

```
Here is some text #variable name# that goes very long with #another variable name# and 
goes longer #another another variable# and some more.
```

I would like to write a regular expression that splits this text into groups like this

```
Group 1: Here is some text 
Group 2: #variable name#
Group 3: that goes very long with 
Group 4: #another variable name#
Group 5: and goes longer 
Group 6: #another another variable#
Group 7: and some more
```

My attempt is poor. I am not able to get my head around this thing

```
(.*?)*(#.*#)*(.*?)*
```

Also, this needs to work in Java.. like the below

```
    import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import static java.util.regex.Pattern.*;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pattern pattern = compile("(([^#]+)|(#[^#]+#)) ");
        String string="Here is some text #variable name# that goes very long with #another variable name# and " +
                "goes longer #another another variable# and some more.";
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
        while(matcher.find()){
            System.out.println(matcher.group());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: is there a `\n` exists in your input?

Comment: `(([^#]+)|(#[^#]+#))`  should do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
([^#]+)|(#[^#]+#)
```

Try this.Grab the captures.See demo.use `g` flag or global match.

http://regex101.com/r/pQ9bV3/1

Comment: The logic is beautiful. I can see how this works. But is there a reason why its not working for me in java? I have updated my question with a code sample.

Comment: @sethu dont see a reason why it shouldnt work.You can try by putting this in a delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the below regex,

```
(#[^#]*#)|\s*(.*?)(?=\s*(?:#|$))
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/hG0qD3/4)

Answer (score 0):

```
(.*?[^\#])|(#.*#)
```

try this regex

Answer (score 0):

This would seem to be what you are looking for:

```
([^#]+|#[^#]+#)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Or if you want the white-space trimmed:

```
\s*([^#]+?(?=\s*#|$)|#[^#]+#)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Answer (score 0):

one more pattern to have trimmed results

```
(#[^#]+#|[^#]+)(?:\s|$)
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/109)

```
(               Capturing Group \1
  #             "#"
  [^#]          Character not in  [^#]
  +             (one or more)(greedy)
  #             "#"
  |             OR
  [^#]          Character not in  [^#]
  +             (one or more)(greedy)
)               End of Capturing Group \1
(?:             Non Capturing Group
  \s            <whitespace character>
  |             OR
  $             End of string/line
)               End of Non Capturing Group
```